# How I do for the Eclipse install my app in the AVD that is already running?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

What happens is that when I Run my Android Application, Eclipse opens another AVD with the same name that I am using.

Couldn't it only install my app in the current AVD?

Comment: Its because your current running AVD is in offline state.Try restarting you ADB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click on project -> Run As -> Run Configration -> Target -> Always Prompt to pick device -> apply ->Run

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Windows->Show View->Others->Android->Devices` and check whether your emulator is visible or not.

If it is visible then just click on it to get focus and if it is not visible then from your Devices option do `Reset adb`.

Comment: Thank you. I am new on Android and Eclipse. Your answer was very useful to me.